# Does fopen create file or update file if the file already exists?

Tags: php, fopen

Does fopen() create file or update file if the file already exists?

Comment: fopen rewrites file contents, if you use 'w' as  mode, if you want to append to it use 'a' mode

Comment: As per the PHP docs, [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) has a `mode` argument, that tells PHP whether to create a new file, overwrite an existing file, append to an existing file, or simply open an existing file.... reading the PHP docs should always be your first step before asking here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on mode. If you use r or r+ it will not create file. If you use w,w+,a,a+,x,X+,c,c+ it will create file.

w and w+ will also remove all content of file and write from beginning. a and a+ will append new content in file.

Comment: what's teh difference between w and w+?